The difference between third conditional and mixed conditional

If I kissed her she wouldn't have hit me

If I had kissed her she wouldn't have hit me


Is there any difference between third conditional and mixed conditional?

I don't think there's much difference in AmE. #2 sounds more natural but #1 will be common.

between 3 ? I've got #3 and #4 in my answer, but what does 3 mean in your question?

...okay, I found this on britishcouncil.org. I can't believe someone got paid to write all that stuff, but never got around to explicitly explaining what difference emphatic had makes.

I think your example 1 If I kissed her she wouldn't have hit me isn't the same as their 1a If she was really my friend, she wouldn't have lied to me. Yours probably refers to a different (but still "possible") Present / Future (you presumably wouldn't be raising doubts about whether you did in fact kiss her in the past). Theirs refers to a different unreal (no longer possible) Past (in reality, she wasn't really my friend. Thats to say, you've misunderstood things. That britishcouncil page wouldn't endorse your example #1 in the first place.

I don't think many people would use OP's #1. You don't always need to use the Perfect, but most people would here. But more common might be...

3 If I'd kissed her she wouldn't have hit me.
...and less common (in speech, but perhaps not in writing) might be...
4 If I had kissed her she would not have hit me.

By which I mean if you're going to use contractions, you should probably contract both verbs UNLESS the first had is given extra stress for emphasis.

2a If I had kissed her she wouldn't have hit me.

Heavy stress on the first had after "negating" if emphasizes that the speaker didn't kiss her, which he now deeply regrets (without heavy stress, he might just be making a matter-of-fact observation, with no particular regret).

The difference between third conditional and mixed conditional is the time when you see the consequences of an action.
"If I had kissed her she wouldn't have hit me" - is the third conditional. Both actions had happened in the past. For example, yesterday you didn't kiss the girl and yesterday she hit you.
"If I kissed her she wouldn't have hit me" - is the mixed conditional (one if them). Here you may see, that the "if-clause" (If I kissed her) looks like part of the second conditional, which is used in present or future tenses. It means that this state or condition still exists in present, it's the same. And the "main clause" (she wouldn't have hit me) looks like part of the third conditional, which is used only in the past.
So the point is that this situation is still present and It has consequences in the past. This grammar structure is designed for cases, when you want to emphasise that the state is the same.You didn't kiss her and she hit you, but you still haven't kissed her yet.
Another example: If I were a man, they would have given me the job.
I didn't get the job, because I'm not a man, but I'm still not a man, It hasn't changed.
